# for loop output in empty container: error message & won't repeat

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I've tried to work this loop in all sorts of ways, and no website that I've come across has helped me solve my problem. I'm relatively new to R and could use some guidance in where my code is going wrong. I'm trying to run a for loop to repeat this sequence 1000 times: create two random sets of numbers "lakea" and "lakeb", run a t-test on the two lakes, and store the resulting p-value of that t-test (significant or not significant) in an empty container (result). I feel like I'm close, but for some reason can't get the process to repeat.

```
result<-vector("list",1000)   #empty container to fill
for(i in 1:1000){
lakea<-rnorm(30,100,15)
lakeb<-rnorm(30,110,15)
    pval<-t.test(lakea,lakeb)$p.value   #stores pvalues from the t-test
    if(pval[i] <= 0.05) result[[i]]<-"stat sig" else   #if statement to name output
    result[[i]]<-"not sig"
}
result
```

The loop results in 1 actual result with the outcome I want ("stat sig" or "not sig"), and then 999 NULL objects within the container.

I've also tried changing my code for the container to be:

```
result<-vector("character",length(1000))
for(i in length(result)){
...
```

which gives a similar result, but creates one long vector in fewer rows than the first code (still with only the first object with the intended output).
I've also tried  changing the container code to be:

```
result<-c(NULL,length(1000))
for(i in result){
...
```

which gives me the first output of either "stat sig" or " not sig", but nothing else.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `if(pval[i] <= 0.05)` *should* be `if(pval <= 0.05)` in this example

Comment: Wow, simple fix. Not sure how I missed that! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can condense your problem down into one line, using a looping construct built for this kind of resampling, and use `ifelse` for the conditional evaluation of the result:

```
replicate( 1000 , ifelse( t.test( rnorm(30,100,15) ,  rnorm(30,100,15 ) )$p.value <= 0.05 , "stat.sig" , "not.sig" ) )
```

Comment: Beat me to `replicate` by 13 seconds. +1 for the really concise code.

Comment: Ok, Mr. One-Liner Expert :-) :-), now write it without any `if` or `ifelse`  .  --> You know, produce a logical value `j` from `j<- (stuff$p.value <= 0.05)` and then `j<-j+1`, and select `answer[j]` where `answer<-c("stat.sig" , "not.sig" )`  .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft do you mean `replicate( 1000 , t.test( rnorm(30,100,15) ,  rnorm(30,100,15 ) )$p.value <= 0.05 )` ? And just using T/F values?

Comment: Yep, basically that's the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some simpler syntax that avoids having to initialize the `result` vector:

```
myfun <- function(){
    lakea<-rnorm(30,100,15)
    lakeb<-rnorm(30,110,15)
    # OP's original code:
     #pval <- t.test(lakea,lakeb)$p.value   #stores pvalues from the t-test
     #if(pval <= 0.05)
     #    result <-"stat sig" else   #if statement to name output
     #result <- "not sig"
    # simplified version:
    result <- ifelse(pval <= 0.05, "sig", "not sig")
}
result <- replicate(1000,myfun())
```

Comment: @SimonO101 Yup, I definitely think we "replicated" each other there. (I hate myself for writing that.)

Comment: FYI you can do `result <- if(pval <= 0.05) "stat sig" else "not sig"`

Comment: @hadley thanks, yes. I was just copying OP's code directly for their benefit.

Comment: @hadley Hope it looks better now :)